# Under Tensorflow 2.0, how to use tf.summary?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow2.0

It seems the use of tf.summary under TF2.0 is different from TF1.x. If I want to visualize multiple scalars (e.g., train_loss, val_loss, etc.) in TensorBoard, how to implement tf.summary in the code. I thought it might be:

```
writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer('summaries')
for epoch in range(epochs):
    ...
    train_loss = ...
    val_loss = ...
    tf.summary.scalar('train_loss', train_loss)
    tf.summary.scalar('val_loss', val_loss)
    writer.flush()
```

But it doesn't work. I think the problem may be from the use of write.flush().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In tensorflow 2.0, you need to set default writer via `.as_default()`. Also, `step` argument must be passed in summary ops. More details can be seen [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/migrate).

```py
writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer("summaries")

for epoch in range(epochs):
    train_loss = ...
    val_loss = ...
    with writer.as_default():
      tf.summary.scalar('train_loss', train_loss, step=epoch)
      tf.summary.scalar('val_loss', val_loss, step=epoch)
    writer.flush()
```